# Class 'ABC' is implemented in both <framework1> and <framework2> one of the two will be used, which one is undefined

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift-package-manager

I have an app which complies the frameworks with swift packages as dependencies.

The frameworks is build in isolation using the same swift packages as dependencies.

On compiling the app, I'm getting warning

Class 'A'(from Swift Package) is implemented in both  and  one of the two will be used, which one is undefined.

How do we resolve this issue?

Comment: Scan through [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is+implemented+in+both+and+one+of+the+two+will+be+used+%5Bswift-package-manager%5D+is%3Aq).